# How to set a label position to border in Kivy?

Tags: python, layout, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivy-language

Hi i have problems with positioning of my labels in Kivy.
I think pictures can describe my problem best.

How it looks like now...
[image: How it looks like now...]

How I want it looks like...
[image: How I want it looks like...]

I want to bind the Label 3 to the right border. I have no Idea how to do this.
My Code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

root = Builder.load_string('''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text: '1'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.17)
        Label:
            text: '2'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.83)
    Label:
        text: '3'
''')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root.size_hint = (1.0, 1.0)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this type of cases there is [`AnchorLayout`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html), which serves to align the widgets to a relative position.

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

root = Builder.load_string('''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text: '1'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.17)
        Label:
            text: '2'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.83)

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        Label:
            text: '3'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: None, None
''')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root.size_hint = (1.0, 1.0)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a [FloatLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html). The following example use a *FloatLayout* without reducing the size of the labels ("2" - size_hint: 1, 0.83) and ("1" - size_hint: 1, 0.17).

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

root = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.10.0

Screen:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: '1'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1, 0.17)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0.8}

        Label:
            text: '2'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.83)

        Label:
            text: '3'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1, 0.17)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.3, 'y': 0.1}
''')


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root.size_hint = (1.0, 1.0)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - AppStartup]

Answer (score 0):

The kivy way of creating an application is putting widgets in widgets. You should try as follows, and i'm sure you'll be able to get what you want with this.

```
root = Builder.load_string('''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text: '1'
            font_size: self.height
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.17)
        BoxLayout:
            Orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.83)
            Label:
                text: '2'
                font_size: self.height
                size_hint: (0.8, 1)
            Label:
                text: '3'
                size_hint: (0.2, 1)
''')
```

Like this your '3' will still be about in the middle of the screen. I think you could change that with `halign`, which should be somewhere in the kivy docs. You could also fix that by adding another `BoxLayout`, this time being `vertical` again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with your solution the '2' label isn't centered anymore. I think that I need a way to set the position of '3' unattached of the other labels. 
Is there a way to set label 3 to absolute position of bottom right corner?

Comment: You could do that as Eyllanesc described! An anchorlayout would be the way to go.